# powershell 2 working with multiple csv files

Tags: powershell, csv, foreach

I have 2 csv files. One with names and the other with a list of phone numbers. i'm trying to loop through each csv file and run a script on the user and name.

```
file examples
Name Number
a      1
b      2
c      3
```

So I need to run a script like a + 1, b + 2, c + 3

trying to use a foreach loop but it not working correctly it's nested incorrectly and can't figure it out.

```
 if ($users){
foreach ($u in $users) 
{ 
 $username= ($u.'Mail')

  
     foreach ($n in $numbers)
     { 
    
    $number = ($n.'ID')
   
     }
```

Comment: If I got it right your problem is that the elements in your csv files are actually unrelated to each other. If the order is the attribute what relates the names to the numbers you can use a for loop and the loop variable as index for your csv files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, in that you need to use a loop, but you want one loop to get data from both files, so in this case you're best off using a `For` loop like this:

```
$Combined = For($i = 0; $i -lt $users.count; $i++) {
    $Props = @{
        Mail = $users[$i].Mail
        ID = $numbers[$i].ID
    }
    New-Object PSObject -Prop $Props
}
$Combined | Export-Csv C:\Path\To\Combined.csv -NoTypeInfo
```

Comment: Nice;  syntactic sugar `[pscustomobject] @{ Mail = $users[$i].Mail; ID = $numbers[$i].ID }` is again worth recommending - not just for concision and efficiency, but because it guarantees the _order_ in which properties are defined - unlike the `New-Object` approach.